# How to connect to remote redis server in NestJS?

Tags: redis, nestjs

I am using Aiven to create free redis server and It has some information below.
[image]

I want to connect my backend to this redis server but I can't. I run my server and It throws error

**"Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.127.206.180:22923
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)"**

This is my config Redis connection. (I connect in local It works normally)

```
CacheModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService): Promise<any> => ({
    store: redisStore,
    host: configService.get('REDIS_HOST'),
    port: configService.get('REDIS_PORT'),
    password: configService.get('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
    // url: configService.get('REDIS_URL'),
    ttl: 120,
    ssl: true,
  }),
}),
```

Anyone can help me solve it? Thank you in advanced!